# What are some good tools to create graphs with vertexes and edges?

Tags: c++, graph

I have implemented some algorithms from graph theory in C++. My teacher wants us to show some examples with graphs, so I need to draw a graph and then explain step by step how my implementation works.

I don't want to use paint for this job so I was wondering is there any tool available that can make your life easier when trying to create weighted graphs with edges and vertexes?

thanks!

Comment: [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/) + [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)? In any case, voting to close -- [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/166663).

Comment: I would use Graphviz to create the visualizations of the graphs and tikz in LaTeX to annotate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, use graphvis.  If you're already using boost.graph for your implementation you can simply write your graphs to graphvis format.